# Which class to create the Retrofit instance in?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have searched everywhere and the tutorials I've seen don't match the documentation given by Retrofit. I think this is a stupid question, as I haven't been able to find an answer for it. I'm brand new at Android programming.

I'm following [Codepath's guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#automated-approach---auto-generating-the-java-classes) and am at the part where it says:

Creating the Retrofit instance

```
To send out network requests to an API, we need to use the [Retrofit 
builder] class and specify the base URL for the service.

// Trailing slash is needed
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.myservice.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

I have no idea which class to put this in. Or do I create a new class for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jonathan has given you plenty of code but I think your question is more of the entry level "How do I use it?" questions, right?

So basically the code you've posted creates a `Retrofit` instance. It's an object capable of creating api interface objects. One `Retrofit` object handles one base url.

You define api endpoints and expected responses by creating `interface`s. Using examples from the website:

Endpoint interface

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("users/{user}/repos")
    Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Then, using the Retrofit instance you created, you can instantiate an implementation of this interface by calling

```
GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

and the simply send requests to the api by calling

```
Call<List<Repo>> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
repos.enqueue(callback) //add a callback where you can handle the response
```

The example posted by Jonathan uses RxJava call adapter, but you should skip that part for now to make it easier for yourself.

EDIT: adding an example requested in the comments.

for this api endpoint --> `https://api.textgears.com/check.php?text=I+is+an+engeneer!&key=DEMO_KEY`

you need

```
@GET("check.php")
Call<YourResponseClass> performCheck(@Query("text") String text, @Query("key") apiKey);
```

This is also an interesting case as you most certainly need to add the apiKey to every request. But it's not a good practice to manually add it as a parameter every single time. There is a solution - `Interceptor`.

```
public class ApiKeyRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    final HttpUrl newUrl = request.url().newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter(Constants.API.PARAM_API_KEY, BuildConfig.NEWS_API_KEY) //add your api key here
            .build();
    return chain.proceed(request.newBuilder()
            .url(newUrl)
            .build());
}
}
```

and tell Retrofit to use it (build an `OkHttpClient`)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new ApiKeyRequestInterceptor())
            .build();

Retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

In this case you don't need an extra field for your key, and you can reduce your method to

```
Call<YourResponseClass> performCheck(@Query("text") String text);
```

Comment: You are right man, Rx is a whole step, but also good to know about it and learn, its way easier to handle responses with Rx than do it with bare hands

Comment: Of course, I use Rx in all my projects but it's still a separate thing, so let him add one brick at a time :)

Comment: Her :) But thank you this explanation was very helpful!

Comment: I am using [this api](https://textgears.com/api/) and am having troubling figuring out what to put in the interface for @GET

Comment: `@GET("check.php")`, everything before that is the base url: `https://api.textgears.com/` and everything after "?" is to be added as @Query parameters in the method definition. I'm gonna add it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Controller to handle the requests.

```
public class RequestController {

private final static String BASE_URL_CLUB = "url";
private static RequestApiEndpoints apiServiceAsync;
private static RequestController instance;
private static final int TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 10000;
private static final TimeUnit TIMEOUT_UNIT = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
private Context context;

private RequestController(Context context) {

    this.context = context;

    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    Retrofit retrofitAsync = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_CLUB)
            .client(createDefaultOkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build();

    apiServiceAsync = retrofitAsync.create(RequestApiEndpoints.class);
}


private OkHttpClient createDefaultOkHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .cache(new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024)) // 10 MB
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    if (Utils.hasInternet(context)) {
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
                    } else {
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24).build();
                    }
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
            .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
            .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
}

public static RequestController getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RequestController(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
public Observable<ResponseObject> getExampleInfo(String param) {
    return apiServiceAsync.getExampleInfo(param).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
}
```

Then your interface:

```
public interface RequestApiEndpoints {

@GET("path/to/request") //without the base url 
Observable<ResponseObject> getExampleInfo(@Query("param") String param);
}
```

Then on your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
...
public static RequestController requestController;
...
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    requestController = RequestController.getInstance(this); 
    ...
}
  public static FPDApplication getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FPDApplication();
    }
    return instance;
}

}
```

Then to access to your RequestController just do the follow:

```
MyApplication.requestController.getExampleInfo(string);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I think understand how to add this to my code now